# Random partitioning given array with given bin sizes

Tags: python, function, numpy, partitioning

> How to randomly partition given array with given bin sizes?

Is there an inbuilt function for that? For example, I want something like
`function(12,(2,3,3,2,2))` to output four partitions of numbers from 1 go 12 (or 0 to 11, doesn't matter). So output may be a list like `[[3,4],[7,8,11],[12,1,2],[5,9],[6,10]]`(or some other efficient data structure). The first argument of the function may be just a number n, in which case it will consider `np.arange(n)` as the input, otherwise it may be any other ndarray.

Of course we can randomly permute the list and then pick the first 2, next 3, next 3, next 2 and last 2 elements. But does there exist something more efficient?

`numpy.partition()` function has a different meaning, it performs a step in quicksort, and I also couldn't find any such function in the `numpy.random` submodule.

Comment: @MSS, I saw that, but couldn't find a way to do it using that. It just selects a random sample from given array, doesn't partition the given array. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Pls check my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following solution:

```
def func(a, b:List):
    # a is integer and b is a python list
    indx = np.random.rand(a).argsort() # Get randomly arranged index
    b = np.array(b)
    return np.r_[np.split(indx,b.cumsum()[:-1])] # split the index and merge
```

Comment: The word in the second argument in your function shows error as is, it runs with small l.

Comment: And then it shows `VisualDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.`

Comment: Can you show exactly what  input you are giving and what output you are expecting to this function?

Comment: You will get the warning because in the output the length of partitioned subarrays  are not same. But  I can see you got the output you expected.